# Firebase ID token has incorrect audience (aud) claim. Expected Make sure the ID token comes from the same Firebase project as the

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, azure-devops, firebase-authentication

I use [Firebase Admin .NET SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-dotnet) with the .Net 6 web API project for Google login. The below code is working fine in the local environment. But when I published the app to Azure App service it gives the below error. I think the issue here is with initializing the `"FirebaseAdminSdk.json"` file. Do you know how to do it in production?

> Firebase ID token has incorrect audience (aud) claim. Expected
> my-firebase-project-id but got
> 272437162012-hagu0iffquo1lb3ko07qtpgenluswaebr.apps.googleusercontent.com.
> Make sure the ID token comes from the same Firebase project as the
> credential used to initialize this SDK

Extension method

```
 public static void ConfigureFirebaseAdminSdk(this IServiceCollection services,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
       
        var pathToFirebaseAdminSdk = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                           "keys", "FirebaseAdminSdk.json"); // I think problem is here

        FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions
        {
            Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(pathToFirebaseAdminSdk)
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
               .AddJwtBearer(options =>
               {
                   var firebaseProjectId = configuration["FirebaseProjectId"];

                   var firebaseSecureTokenUrl = configuration["FirebaseSecureTokenUrl"];

                   options.Authority = firebaseSecureTokenUrl + firebaseProjectId;

                   options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                   {
                       ValidateIssuer = true,
                       ValidIssuer = firebaseSecureTokenUrl + firebaseProjectId,
                       ValidateAudience = true,
                       ValidAudience = firebaseProjectId,
                       ValidateLifetime = true
                   };
               });
    }
```

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins Yes, it was a configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, your `FirebaseAdminSdk.json` is for a different project than where you are running the code. From the `my-firebase-project-id` in the message it seems that it may be from your local emulator project.

You will need to make sure the JSON file and the `configuration["FirebaseProjectId"]` are for the same project.

Comment: Yes, that is the same. I have hidden my firebase project name using this `my-firebase-project-id`. Otherwise, it is the same and I do not use Emulator here too.

Comment: I get this error after creating environments. My front end initialises Firebase with a name, so I thought maybe the back end needs to use the same name. But I still get the error after making it the same name. My FirebaseAdminSdk.json file is for the correct firebase project so no idea what is going wrong.

Comment: Okay sorted it. `services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options => { options.Authority =` section was still pointing to the old firebase project id.